# Получить список ключей из x32 и x64 реестра, Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, реестр

Есть два раздела реестра, находящиеся по пути

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall
```

(для x32 и для x64). Для того чтобы открыть конкретный раздел, рекомендуют использовать OpenBaseKey:

```
var x32Tree = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
var x64Tree = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);

var a = x32Tree.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames();
var b = x64Tree.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\WOW6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall").GetSubKeyNames();
```

Я ожидаю увидеть разные коллекции а и б, но, на выходе, я вижу одну и ту же коллекцию, сформированную из запроса к x64 ветке реестра (значений что есть в x32 ветке в обоих коллекциях нет). Редактор реестра видит обе ветки, соответственно, и значения которых я не могу вытащить там тоже есть.

Как быть? Есть ли способы получить коллекцию из 32битной ветки, и отдельную коллекцию для x64 ветки со соответствующими именами ключей из этих веток?

Comment: а если у x64Tree запросить по первому ключу, который без WOW6432Node?

Comment: @Monk, вы решили мою проблему! Огромнейшее вам Спасибо! Пожалуйста, объясните механику в ответе, чтобы вопрос можно было закрыть

Comment: Я механику и не знаю, просто в курсе, что не надо явно запрашивать WOW6432Node в нормальной ситуации.